# Dividing canceled number

Tags: fractions

I want to have this look.  [image]

for example

```
$\dfrac{cancelNewCommandTop{1}{5}} {\cancelNewCommandBottom{2}{4}}
. \dfrac{\cancelNewCommandTop{1}{2}{cancelNewCommandBottom{1}{5}=$
```

I can't make the function. I only know that i have to use \cancel and \overset.

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,cancel}
\newcommand{\cancelNewCommandTop}[2]{\overset{#1}{\cancel{#2}}}
\newcommand{\cancelNewCommandBottom}[2]{\underset{#1}{\cancel{#2}}}
\begin{document}
$\dfrac{\cancelNewCommandTop{1}{5}}{\cancelNewCommandBottom{2}{4}}
\cdot \dfrac{\cancelNewCommandTop{1}{2}}{\cancelNewCommandBottom{1}{5}}=$
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\genfrac` (presented below using `\nolinefrac`) or an `array` (presented below using `\stackfrac`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cancel,amsmath}

\newcommand{\nolinefrac}{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}}
\newcommand{\stackfrac}[1]{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{array}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \dfrac
    {\nolinefrac{1}{\cancel{5}}}
    {\nolinefrac{\cancel{4}}{2}}
  \cdot
  \dfrac
    {\nolinefrac{1}{\cancel{2}}}
    {\nolinefrac{\cancel{5}}{1}}
  =
  \dfrac
    {\stackfrac{1 \\ \cancel{5}}}
    {\stackfrac{\cancel{4} \\ 2}}
  \cdot
  \dfrac
    {\stackfrac{1 \\ \cancel{2}}}
    {\stackfrac{\cancel{5} \\ 1}}
  =
  \dfrac
    {1}
    {2}
  = \dfrac{5}{4} \cdot \dfrac{2}{5}
  = \dfrac{5}{5} \cdot \dfrac{2}{4}
  = 1 \cdot \dfrac{1}{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

However, there are more clear was of presenting this (on the right-hand side of `\dfrac{1}{2}`).

Comment: Good! I liked the \stackfrac function. Can you help me to make other function like \stacksfrac but for for normal numbers with denominator. Like that - https://imgur.com/bkX5Vkg

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov: Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3PEA.png)? You can use `\newcommand{\stackbelow}[1]{\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{array}}` (a `[t]`op-aligned `array`) and `\newcommand{\stackabove}[1]{\begin{array}[b]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{array}}` (a `[b]`ottom-aligned `array`).

Comment: I need it only for normal number, no fraction. For this to type https://imgur.com/bkX5Vkg for example \stackAboveCancel{1}{5}  and get the result from the picture.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov: Then you can use `\newcommand{\stackAboveCancel}[2]{\begin{array}[b]{@{}c@{}}#1\\\cancel{#2}\end{array}}`.

Comment: I have tried it, good. But is there anyway the upper number to be closer to the bottom number, like in \genfrac?

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov: Sure. Use `\newcommand{\stackAboveCancel}[2]{{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.2}\begin{array}[b]{@{}c@{}}#1\\\cancel{#2}\end{array}}}` and tweak the value of `0.2`. Increasing it will push the values apart; decreasing it (down to `0`) will bring them together.

Comment: Nice. I made similar function for stacking below. Do you know how to make the function to ignore the spacing i have. I am using \begin{spacing}{1.5} and the spacing is applied to this new function i have different fractions compared to \dfrac.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov: Are you using [`setspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/setspace)?

Comment: Werner: Yes, I am using it.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov: You can add `\setstretch{1}` as part of the definition *within* a closed group.